# login con php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, mysqli

estoy danto mis primeros pasos en PHP y estoy trabajando en un login, trato de comparar la contraseña que esta en la base de datos y la que el usuario ingreso, pero no logro que funcione,
Este es el codigo que tengo:

```
// data sent from form login.html 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$password = $_POST['password'];

// Query sent to database
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email = '$email'");
$ps=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * Password from users WHERE Email = '$email'");

// Variable $row hold the result of the query
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

// Variable $hash hold the password hash on database
//$hash = $row['Password'];

/* 
password_Verify() function verify if the password entered by the user
match the password hash on the database. If everything is ok the session
is created for one minute. Change 1 on $_SESSION[start] to 5 for a 5 minutes session.
*/

if (strcmp($password,$ps)==0) { 

    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['name'] = $row['Name'];
    $_SESSION['start'] = time();
    $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (1 * 3660) ;                     

    echo "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'><strong>Welcome!</strong> $row[Name]            
    // <p><a href='edit-profile.php'>Edit Profile</a></p>   
    // <p><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></p></div>";   

    // <a href="donde-estamos.html">Donde estamos</a>
}   
 else {
     echo "mal";
    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Email or Password are incorrects!
    <p><a href='login.html'><strong>Please try again!</strong></a></p></div>";          
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Mi recomendación, desde la experiencia, es que no hagas el login tú mismo. Estás perdiendo un tiempo valioso en algo que ya está bien hecho por otros. Utiliza un framework como Laravel, CodeIgniter, Zend o similares. Sé que programar todas estas cosas es divertido, todos hemos pasado por ahí, pero no vale la pena.

Comment: yo difiero, en realidad si vale la pena, pues es aprendizaje personal, en todo caso te servira para cuando requieras personalizar funciones en algún que otro framework, por otro lado depende de como estes creando y almacenando la clave, yo en lo personal utilizo `crypt` para crearlas y luego `password_verify`para comparar el hash almacenado con la clave del formulario